# Extracting specific text from a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Can someone help me with the correct script to extract the following:

1. Extract the first instance of text between TTT and CHECK-Hello for the line starting with 'D' word, not the second one.
2. Extract the first instance of text between :19: and :19B: for the line starting with 'D' word

Sample Data:

```
DHDR    .///20198782827372
D      17639937     0     50k     0     6           TTT1234 CHECK-Hello       ksdhujshds     :19: 782382689jds :19B:kahdhsd 
D      97837283     0     10k     0     6           TTT3456 CHECK-Hello       akjdhjdks     :19: 782382689jds :19B: kshdhd TTT3927837 CHECK-Hello       
M      98382388     0     20k     0     6           TTT3457 CHECK-Hello       ishadhsjh       :19: 782382689jds :19B
```

Current Code:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*.csv')
strings = []
for file in files:
  with open(file, "r", encoding='UTF-8') as fobj:
      text = fobj.read()
  import re
  a = re.compile(':19:(.*) :19B:')
  b=re.compile('TTT(.*)CHECK-Hello')
  z = a.findall(text)
  k=b.findall(text)
  if len(z)>0 and len(k)>0:

      strings.append(z + "," + k)
```

Output needed:

```
TTT_ID     ID
1234       782382689
3456       782382689
```

Comment: What error are you seeing from your current code?

Comment: A Minimal Verifiable Complete Example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be good here.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
import re
import csv
files = glob.glob('testing.csv')
strings = []
a = re.compile(':19:(.*) :19B:')
b = re.compile('TTT(.*)CHECK-Hello')
for file in files:
    with open(file, "r", encoding='UTF-8') as fobj:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(fobj, delimiter=',')
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[0].strip() == 'D':
                z = a.findall(row[1])
                k = b.findall(row[1])
                strings.append(k[0][:4].strip() + "," + z[0][:-3].strip())
print(strings)
```